# Vanilla JS - Toggle class outside element

Tags: javascript

Like in topic. I search other way to do this, but it won't work good. After using button immediately function give me "removing" :/ Any lead to a good lead?

```
var button = document.querySelector(".menu-icon");
var menu = document.querySelector(".mymenu");

function drop(e){
  menu.classList.add("show");
  document.addEventListener("click", hide(e));
}
function hide(e){
  if(!menu.contains(e.target)) menu.classList.remove("show");
}
button.addEventListener("click", drop);
```

Comment: In that line you call the hide-function directly: document.addEventListener("click", hide(e));  because you write it like that hide(e) instead of just hide.

Comment: and if you want to your toggle works, you should remove dropping eventListener in the drop function and add it again in the hide function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, you need to parse the hide function into 'addEventListener', not call it, that will parse the return of the function (null), and call it immediately and not on click.

So it would look like this instead:

```
function drop(e) {
  menu.classList.add('show');
  document.addEventListener("click", hide); 
}
```